# How to hide the NULL values in list item get from store in sencha touch

Tags: sencha-touch, extjs, sencha-touch-2, sencha-charts

[image]I have implemented an application in **sencha touch.**

in that i have a list view , **i retrieve the data from the store**,

in data base in some fields i have inserted **null values,{No selection}.**

the corresponding fields in list view are displayed as **NULL,**

But i want to display an **`empty space`** instead of **NULL,**

```
        {
                  xtype: 'list',

                  itemTpl: [
                            '<div id="wrapper">'+
                            '<div class="frt">{Name}</div>'+
                            '<div class="frt">{Title}</div>'+
                            '<div class="frt">{Contact}</div>'+
                            '<div class="frt">{Zip}</div>'+
                            '</div>'
                            ],
                  store: 'ContactsDataBase'
             }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
{
       xtype: 'list',
       itemTpl: [
                   '<div id="wrapper">'+
                   '<div class="frt"><tpl if="Name != null">{Name}</tpl></div>'+
                   '<div class="frt"><tpl if="Title != null">{Title}</tpl></div>'+
                   '<div class="frt">{Contact}</div>'+
                   '<div class="frt">{Zip}</div>'+
                   '</div>'
                ],
        store: 'ContactsDataBase'
}
```

Visit [Sencha Touch docu site](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/api/Ext.XTemplate) for more information.

Cheers, Oleg

Comment: Having an issue with this: I have this code:
temTpl: '<div class="contact"><h1>{name} <tpl if="active != null"><span class="active">{active}</span></tpl><tpl if="inactive != null"><span class="inactive">{inactive}</span></tpl></h1><span class="rating">{rating}</span> &middot; <span class="rating">{amount}</span> </div>',

Answer (score 0):

A slight modified version

```
itemTpl: [
               '<div id="wrapper">'+
               '<div class="frt"><tpl if="values.Name">{Name}</tpl></div>'+
               '<div class="frt"><tpl if="values.Title">{Title}</tpl></div>'+
               '<div class="frt">{Contact}</div>'+
               '<div class="frt">{Zip}</div>'+
               '</div>'
            ]
```